# Default value for template constant in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to replace a global buffer size to one that can be modifiable for tests. The current code is something like:

```
static const uint32_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 8;

class BufferWrapper {
.
.
.

char buffer_[BUFFER_SIZE];
};
```

This causes a problem when I'm trying to change the BUFFER_SIZE for tests. Thus, I was hoping to make the BUFFER_SIZE a template constant, and having a default value for said constant so that I only need to specify it during tests, something like:

```
static const uint32_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 8;

template <uint_32 SIZE = BUFFER_SIZE>
class BufferWrapper {
.
.
.

char buffer_[SIZE];
};
```

That way, previous declarations can still compile like:

```
BufferWrapper buf
```

But during a test, I could write something like this to test a buffer of 1KB:

```
BufferWrapper<1024> test_buf;
```

My question is, is it possible to provide a default for a template value, and how would I do it? The error I get with the above when I declare something like `BufferWrapper buf;` is:

```
error: use of class template 'BufferWrapper' requires template arguments; argument deduction not allowed in function prototype
```

Comment: Maybe you are on an older compiler not supporting template argument deduction on variables? Have you tried `BufferWrapper<> test_buf;`?

Comment: The error hints at code that is not exactly like what you show here. Can you share a [mcve], please?

Comment: The problem is the buffer size must be known at compile time, but I can only use a static const to define the size. Removing the const qualifier throws an error.

Comment: BUFFER_SIZE is ```uint32_t``` while your template parameter is ```uint_32```, and you probably want the same spelling.  Also, after your change, you need to say ```BufferWrapper<>``` (with the angle brackets) buffer on pre-c++17 compilers to get the default.
You might consider doing like the STL does, and define your BufferWrapper as the BasicBufferWrapper, then ```using BufferWrapper = BasicBufferWrapper<BUFFER_SIZE>;``` so existing code doesn't need to change.  Then you don't need a default, just pass it in here.

Answer (score 5):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739632/1782465) states, the code is fine since C++17. However, if you do not have access to that, you can still get around the need to change all existing code to use `BufferWrapper<>` instead of `BufferWrapper`.

Do this by renaming `BufferWrapper` to something else (e.g. `BufferWrapperTemplate`) and providing a type alias to the default-sized version:

```
template <uint_32 SIZE = BUFFER_SIZE>
class BufferWrapperTemplate {
.
.
.

char buffer_[SIZE];
};

typedef BufferWrapperTemplate<> BufferWrapper;
```

This way, all existing code can keep using `BufferWrapper`, and tests can use `BufferWrapperTemplate<42>` where needed.

Comment: `typedef BufferWrapper BufferWrapperTemplate<>` I think those identifiers are backwards.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure, but if the thing I am writing is a workaround for older compilers, it might be best to stick to old syntax.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with the shown program in C++17.

Prior to C++17, you must provide the template argument list even if it is empty:

```
BufferWrapper<> test_buf;
```

In such case you can avoid changing the client code by using a type alias:

```
template <uint_32 SIZE = BUFFER_SIZE>
class BufferWrapperTemplate;

using BufferWrapper = BufferWrapperTemplate<>;
```

Comment: Or call it `BufferWrapperImpl` instead, then provide `using BufferWrapper = BufferWrapperImpl<>`. That's what I'd do.

Comment: Heh, yeah, like that.

Comment: I see, yea I am not using C++17. Thank you for the help!